# How to handle a web pop-up that displays only once, mostly first login after a refresh

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd

How to handle a web pop-up that displays only once after the refresh/ release. From the second execution onward this pop-up will not display and will error as "no such element: Unable to locate element" (thats correct as element dont exist/visible)

Tried switching the iframe, sleep method , also .Isdisplayed() & .IsEnabled() methods as given below -

```
    By wndOrg =  By.className("popup-header-text");
    boolean blnDisplay = driver.findElement(wndOrg).isEnabled();
    if (blnDisplay){ driver.findElement(txtKey).Click(); }
```

Comment: Can you show us which popup it is ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I remember an answer, to a similar question, using a try/catch

```
try
{
  // do webdriver stuff
}
catch
{
  // do nothing
}
```